# Веб сокеты в Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Не могу разобраться с веб сокетами в Laravel 5.4.

В Laravel до версии 5.4 при создании события, это события наследовалось от класса Events и при работе с сокетами, передаваемые данные прослушивались и отправлялись, а начиная с версии Laravel 5.4 это события не наследуется от класса events. При попытке получить данные отправляемые одним клиентом другому ничего не происходит, та как нет слушателя или может быть причина в другом, а при указании наследования, выбиваются ошибки и соответственно не работают сокеты. 
Подскажите плиз как правильно это сделать самый элементарный чат между двумя пользователями на версии Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь что бы пользоваться веб-сокетами надо наследовать интерфейс ShouldBroadcast.

Интерфейс ShouldBroadcast

Когда пользователь просматривает один из своих заказов, надо показывать ему обновления статуса, не требуя обновлять страницу. Вместо этого будем вещать обновления в приложение по мере их создания. Итак, нам надо отметить событие ShippingStatusUpdated интерфейсом ShouldBroadcast. Таким образом Laravel поймёт, что надо вещать это событие при его возникновении:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ShippingStatusUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  //
}
```

Интерфейс ShouldBroadcast требует, чтобы в событии был определён метод broadcastOn(). Этот метод отвечает за возврат каналов, на которые надо вещать событие. В генерируемых классах событий уже определена пустая заготовка этого метода, нам остаётся только заполнить её. Нам надо, чтобы у создателя заказа была возможность просмотреть обновления статуса, поэтому мы будем вещать событие на приватный канал, привязанный к заказу:

```
/**
 * Получить каналы, на которые надо вещать событие.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
  return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->update->order_id);
}
```

Полная статья тут : https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/broadcasting